# Pagination - 2 items per page on page 1, 10 items per page on other pages

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, limit, offset

I need very specific thing - I want to show pagination for N items and my goal is to show only  the first 2 items on page 1 and the rest of items as usual (for example 10 per page). I'm not able to skip the 8 items on first page and move them to the second page. Any advices?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

In first page put the SQL query with LIMIT 0,2
On second page LIMIT 2,10
On third page LIMIT 12,10
In PHP you can do this like this:

```
 <?php
 if($p==1){
      $start=0;
      $amount=2;
 }else{  
      $start=$p*10-18;
      $amount=10;
 }
 $sql="SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $start,$amount";
```

Comment: In case First page = page 1 and second page = page 2, in case if you use number 0 for fist page, you should substract by 8